# SPSS syntax or Python: For each value of x, how many different values of y are there?

Tags: python, syntax, arcgis, spss, esri

I have two variables of interest, for which there are no duplicates between the two, or for x. y has duplicates as it only has 4 options:

1. Provider anonymous ID (variable x)
2. Provider type (variable y) ... only 4 options (family doc, rheumatologist, surgeon, internist)

I want to find out how many times one unique provider ID (x) is associated with a different type of provider (y).

For example, provider ID 101, has listed family doctor in one record, but rheumatologist in another.

**List the values of y that are associated with each value of x**

SPSS syntax, through the GUI, or even in python is much appreciated.

Let me know if any other info would help.

Comment: It sounds like you just want `Crosstabs` on `x` by `y`.  You can find it in the GUI by going to `Analyze` -> `Descriptive Statistics` -> `Crosstabs`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what I think you are asking is to use `CASESTOVARS` to flatten the data file so each row is a unique ID and then the different provider types are in separate variables (wide format).

Here is a quick example.

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID Provider (2F1.0).
BEGIN DATA
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
3 2
3 3
END DATA.
DATASET NAME Sim.

SORT CASES BY ID Provider.
CASESTOVARS /ID = ID /VIND ROOT=Prov_ /COUNT NProviders /INDEX = Provider.
```

If you do `LIST ALL.` then the results for this example are:

```
ID NProviders Prov_1 Prov_2 Prov_3 

 1       3       1      1      1 
 2       1       1      0      0 
 3       2       0      1      1
```

The `NProviders` variable lists how many separate providers each individual ID has, and the dummy variables `Prov_1` to `Prov_3` list the specific types.